# How to use Vue.js with A 3D product spinner for vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

'Hi guys!' I'm currently trying to inject the 'vue-product-spinner'(https://github.com/micheleriva/vue-product-spinner) in my project !
I really don't know how this work 'especially in Where i put my images? Do I need to make an external file.js to put them inside as arrays ? would really appreciate some help